# post function in django formview not called when jquery post is used

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I have to call `SearchView` when "search" button is clicked. With a few print statements, I could see that `SearchView` is being called but post function in the `SearchView` is not called.

Below is the code I have used in SearchView:

```
    class SearchView(FormView):
        template_name = 'search.html'
        #form_class = SearchForm
        success_url = '/mypage/downloadresult'
        print(" i am inside SearchView")

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            # form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            form_class =SearchForm
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            # form_class = self.get_form_class()
            # form = self.get_form(form_class)
            print(" i am inside post")

            if form.is_valid():
                if self.request.is_ajax():
                   // handle form and generate result
```

Below is the display view for my form:

```
    class DisplayView(FormView):
        template_name = 'search.html'
        form_class = SearchForm
        print(" i am inside displayview")
        success_url = '/sampleapp/search'
```

When the form is displayed using the `DisplayView` above, once the user clicks on "search" button, `SearchView` is called on successful form post.

Url patterns in sample app:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        #url('', SearchView.as_view()),
        #url('', SearchView.as_view()),
        url('', displayformview.DisplayView.as_view(), name='displayview'),
        url(r'^search/$', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
        url(r'^downloadresult/$', downloadresultview.DownloadResultView.as_view(), name='downloadresult')
    ]

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^', include(‘sampleapp.urls')),
    ]
```

Below is the jquery i am using:

```
 $('#search').click(function(){
    $.post('/sampleapp/search', $(this).serialize(), function(){
        //alert("submit called")
    })
    .done(function(){
        alert("done")
    })
})
```

I am not sure if the above jquery is acutally sending the form data. If someone can help me understand how to send the form data using jquery and successfully call the post function, it will be really helpful.

I tried debugging using print statement. I could see that post function in `SearchView` is never called and "I am inside post" is never printed in console".

Comment: actually, you tell jquery to post in that url `'/sampleapp/search` and I dont' see in your django code anywhere you have added it in your urls patterns

Answer (score 0):

SearchView is never called because the urls that you have set up here `$.post('/sampleapp/search'` does not exist.

try

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(‘sampleapp.urls')), ---- remove that line
    url(r'^sampleapp/', include(‘sampleapp.urls'))
]
```

or

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url('', SearchView.as_view()),
    #url('', SearchView.as_view()),
    url('', displayformview.DisplayView.as_view(), name='displayview'),
    url(r'^sampleapp/search/$', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^downloadresult/$',  downloadresultview.DownloadResultView.as_view(), name='downloadresult')
]
```

Comment: I tried the above. SearchView is being called. So I am getting "I am inside SearchView" printed in console. But control is not going inside the "post" function in SearchView. So, "I am inside post" is never printed. I am also getting "csrf token is missing or incorrect. But I have added "{% csrf token %}" inside the form in "search.html".

Comment: take a look in your console or your browser to see it the jquery has hit your backend code. you will probably see POST 200, or 304. or POST 500 in case of server error

Comment: Yes it is working now. But I have another issue now. I have posted it below. If you can help me with it, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is working now. But now i have another issue:

I have the search button which when clicked performs the search. I want the user to be able to download the zip file generated on download button click. I tried the above code. But as soon as I click the search button, download happens. The downloaded file is .zip which when clicked opens .cpgz which doesn’t have any data.

Here is the code below:

```
 def post(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
       zip_dir = "result_for_query_{}.zip".format(query_word)
       s = StringIO.StringIO()
       z = zipfile.ZipFile(s, 'w')
   filename = "{}_{}.txt".format(query_word, doc_id)
   # zip_dir = "result_for_query_{}.zip".format(query_word)
   z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_dir, 'a')
   self.write_to_file(filename, doc, z)
   z.close()
  response = HttpResponse(s.getvalue(), content_type='application/zip')
  response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s" % zip_dir
  return response
```

HTML

Download